# Else always returned in condition- python phonebook project

Tags: python

Hi why my program isn't working ?

```
 elif begin == 4:
    firstname = input('Enter a firstname:')
    lastname = input('Enter a lastname:')
    phone = input('Enter a phone number:')
    imp = (f'\'{firstname}\'\'{lastname}\'\'{phone}\'')
    
    
    
    with open('Phonebook','r') as firstfile, open('Reception','a') as secondfile:
        
            if lastname and firstname and phone in firstfile: 
                
                secondfile.write(imp)
                print('phonebook exported!')
            else:
                print('This phonebook doesn\'t exist !')
```

It always return the else and idk why

[image]

What is it ? ( I did this after applying the answers )

My file is not closed why it displays this

Comment: What does the `Phonebook` file look like?

Comment: `lastname and firstname and phone in firstfile` isn't doing what you think.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

First, Your `if` statement probably doesn't do what you think it does.

You've written:

```
            if lastname and firstname and phone in firstfile:
```

That statement is more accurately written like this:

```
            if (lastname) and (firstname) and (phone in firstfile):
```

That is, you are treating `lastname` and `firstname` as boolean
values, which means they will always evaluate to `True` when
non-empty, and then you're checking if `phone in firstfile`.

This is your second problem: you can't use `in` to check if a string
exists in a file; that condition will always return `False`. You need to read the file content into a variable, giving you something like:

```
    with open('Phonebook','r') as firstfile, open('Reception','a') as secondfile:
        
            # read the file into a string
            firstcontent = firstfile.read()

            # now we can check if `<some_string_var> in firstcontent`
            if lastname in firstcontent and firstname in firstcontent and phone in firstcontent: 
                
                secondfile.write(imp)
                print('phonebook exported!')
            else:
                print('This phonebook doesn\'t exist !')
```

You could simplify that condition using the `all` builtin:

```
if all(x in firstcontent for x in [firstname, lastname, phone]):
```

---

Here's a demonstration of it working. Assuming that I have a file "Phonebook" that contains the following content:

```
bob example 123-456-7890
```

And this code:

```py
firstname = input("Enter a firstname:")
lastname = input("Enter a lastname:")
phone = input("Enter a phone number:")
imp = f"'{firstname}''{lastname}''{phone}'"

with open("Phonebook", "r") as firstfile, open("Reception", "a") as secondfile:

    # read the file into a string
    firstcontent = firstfile.read()

    # now we can check if `<some_string_var> in firstcontent`

    if all(x in firstcontent for x in [firstname, lastname, phone]):
        secondfile.write(imp)
        print("phonebook exported!")
    else:
        print("This phonebook doesn't exist !")
```

If I provide responses that match an entry in the phonebook:

```
$ python phonebook.py
Enter a firstname:bob
Enter a lastname:example
Enter a phone number:123-456-7890
phonebook exported!
$ cat Reception
'alice''example''123''bob''example''123-456-7890'
```

Whereas if I provide a response that doesn't match:

```
$ python phonebook.py
Enter a firstname:alice
Enter a lastname:example
Enter a phone number:987-654-3210
This phonebook doesn't exist !
```

Comment: Okay thanks I wanted to do like an "export" it's an export or not ? When you put data in one file to another ?

Comment: It doesn't ..work

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example that shows that yes, it actually does work.